# CryptVerifyTimeStampSignature returning CRYPT_E_ASN1_BADTAG

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, cryptoapi, authenticode

I am trying to verify the timestamp of a signature with the `CryptVerifyTimeStampSignature` Windows Crypto API function. I am stuggling to understand what exactly should be passed into the `pbTSContentInfo` parameter.

```
BOOL CryptVerifyTimeStampSignature(
    _In_      const BYTE                     pbTSContentInfo,
                    DWORD                    cbTSContentInfo,
    _In_opt_  const DWORD                    pbData,
                    DWORD                    cbData,
    _In_opt_        HCERTSTORE               hAdditionalStore,
    _Out_           PCRYPT_TIMESTAMP_CONTEXT ppTsContext,
    _Out_opt_       PCCERT_CONTEXT           *ppTsSigner,
    _Out_opt_       HCERTSTORE               *phStore
);
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd433804(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation states that `pbTSContentInfo` should contain:

> A pointer to a buffer that contains time stamp content.

I am unsure what exactly this pointer should point to and where I can retrieve it from. The signature I am validating is an Authenticode signature on an executable. So far I have tried passing the encoded message returned by `CryptMsgGetParam` however this returns CRYPT_E_ASN1_BADTAG.

Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: Looks like a documentation bug to me. The true signature of `CryptVerifyTimeStampSignature` takes a `const BYTE*` parameter as its first argument (as indicated by the `pb` prefix).

Comment: Ah yeah sorry, I managed to work that out, I can't work out where to get the buffer from that I need to pass?

Comment: of course in msdn page error - must be `const BYTE  *pbTSContentInfo` as and declared in `wincrypt.h`

Comment: *//  pbTSContentInfo
//      [in] Points to a buffer with timestamp content.
//      These bytes are the same as returned in response by CRYPT_TIMESTAMP_CONTEXT::pbEncoded*

Comment: @RbMm as far as I can tell the only way to retrieve a `CRYPT_TIMESTAMP_CONTEXT` is a call to `CryptRetrieveTimeStamp` which is the function used to create a timestamp for a signature. I guess what I need is to understand how to extract a `CRYPT_TIMESTAMP_CONTEXT`from a signature of a file. So far I have extracted the signature using `CryptQueryObject`.